# calculate amount that was due at any point in time?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I have 2 tables, one shows me any payments that were made and another is a schedule that shows me when we expected to receive these payments and how much we expect to receive, like the below..

[image]

I am trying to work out how to add a column to my first table that looks up how much we expected to have at the time a payment was made in the first table. So for my example, I should be able to see that when we received 500 on 11 Jan 2022, we expected to have 490 at that point in time. And when we received 50 on 4th feb 2022, we expected to have 550 at that point in time. So I would be able to add a column to calculate differences like the below..

[image]

I have my query written out to join on the invoiceID which is the easy bit.. I just can't get my head around how I would join on the dates to get the output I need.

What would be the best way to achieve this, can someone point me in the correct direction?

Answer (score 0):

We can add the figures from schedule using  `max(expected) ... where date <= DatePaid` and then use `sum() over`to get the running total.
We then use these figures to calculate the amount paid in advance, or behind if negative, in the last column.

> ```
> create table payments (
> invoiceId int,
> paymentAmount int,
> datePaid date);
> ```

> ```
> insert into payments values
> (493,500,'2022-01-11'),
> (493,50,'2022-02-04'),
> (494,500,'2022-02-01'),
> (494,100,'2022-03-01');
> ```

> ```
> create table schedule (
> scheduleId int,
> invoiceId int,
> expectedAmount int,
> expectedDate date);
> ```

> ```
> insert into schedule values
> (1,493,490,'2022-01-10'),
> (2,493,550,'2022-02-03'),
> (3,494,300,'2022-02-28');
> ```

> ```
> select
>   p.datePaid,
>   p.invoiceId,
>   p.paymentAmount,
>   sum(paymentAmount) over 
>       (partition by p.InvoiceId 
>       order by p.datePaid) TotalPaid,
>   max(s.expectedAmount) Expected,
>   sum(paymentAmount) over 
>       (partition by p.InvoiceId 
>       order by p.datePaid) 
>   - max(s.expectedAmount) Advance
> from payments p
> join schedule s on p.invoiceId = s.invoiceID
> where p.datePaid >= s.expectedDate
> group by 
>   p.invoiceId,
>   p.paymentAmount,
>   p.datePaid 
> order by p.datePaid
> ```

> ```
> datePaid   | invoiceId | paymentAmount | TotalPaid | Expected | Advance
> :--------- | --------: | ------------: | --------: | -------: | ------:
> 2022-01-11 |       493 |           500 |       500 |      490 |      10
> 2022-02-04 |       493 |            50 |       550 |      550 |       0
> 2022-03-01 |       494 |           100 |       100 |      300 |    -200
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d9e0a935eb7fb51e8e581719c949eab3)*